# Left border disappears on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I made a website using Twitter Bootstrap.

http://www.photous.org/en/pictures

It works fine on desktop browsers but on the mobile browser (I tested on iOS Chrome) the left margin and border disappears.
I understand that the initial load hides the side as the width doesn't fit but even if I zoom it out the lost margin & border don't come back.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: its not responsive? wht u have done?

Answer (score 0):

Please include all the code inside

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

       Your code here....

    </div>
```

Now your website will become responsive..

Comment: I don't want my website to be responsive. I just want it to be able to display all the areas of the page by zooming.